# Cannot serialize log message using NoSQLAppender in Log4j2

Tags: mongodb, scala, log4j, mongodb-java, log4j2

Could you guys demonstrate how you use NoSQLAppender in Log4j2 (2.0-beta8) with MongoDB ?

I'm using Scala (although I don't think it's relevant).

Java Mongo DB driver I have is 2.11.2

Appender throws following exception

```
2013-07-31 18:19:27,831 ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender databaseAppender java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.Level
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:270)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:174)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:120)
    at com.mongodb.DefaultDBEncoder.writeObject(DefaultDBEncoder.java:27)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(OutMessage.java:289)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:239)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:204)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:148)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:91)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.nosql.mongo.MongoDBConnection.insertObject(MongoDBConnection.java:61)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I ended up implementing transformer for Level enum like this

```
class LevelBSONEncoder extends org.bson.Transformer {
  def transform(o: Any): AnyRef =
    o match {
      case level: org.apache.logging.log4j.Level => new java.lang.Integer(level.intLevel())
    }
}

// which is used like this

org.bson.BSON.addEncodingHook(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.ERROR.getClass, new LevelBSONEncoder())
```

If anyone know more elegant solution let me know.

PS. Well, that was quick. I reported the bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-330 and maintainers confirmed suggested fix will be incorporated to repo.